# JQuery "OR" in selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Okay, so I've been using JQuery for a while now, I'm in the process of going through some code and trying to make it a bit more shorthand (one JS file I'm working on is 2000+ lines of JQuery for one page :S).

Here's my question, is it possible to do something like an `Or` selector? Something like:

```
$("#element1Id and #element2Id")
```

I know I can pattern match that using

```
$("[id^=element][id&=Id]")
```

But the problem is, I have a LOT of stuff on the page that can match my ID selectors in question and I've always wondered if you could do a this or that, I've needed it in other situations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#element1Id, #element2Id')
```

---

**[Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**

> **Description:** Selects the combined results of all the specified
>   selectors.
>
> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a
>   single result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way
>   to select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)
>   method.

Comment: WOW that easy, I can't believe it! Rob, you hero :)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't go that far. I'm just zis guy, you know?